# Is there a Monodevelop shortcut to navigate between members/fields of a class?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop

Seems that the functionality already exists in MonoDevelop, but it is only accesible by clicking with the mouse in the navigation bar (don't know its exact name) that appears just below the opened files tabs (see attached screenshot)

Does anyone knows if you can trigger that navigation bar using a keyboard shortcut?

[image]